# R: Calculate SD in each row over a selection of columns after removing minimum and maximum

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to compute the standard deviation for each row in a data frame over a selection of columns after removing the minimum and the maximum in that selection. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:100), 10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

I managed to calculate the sd of my columns of interest (1:4) for each row:

```
dat <- transform(dat, sd = apply(dat[,1:4], 1, sd))
show(dat)

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5       sd
1 27 58 21 95 63 33.95463
2 38 91 90 67  7 24.93324
```

However, I can't figure out how to exclude `min(dat[1,1:4])` and `max(dat[1,1:4])` before calculating `sd()`.
The result should be this:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5       sd
1 27 58 21 95 63 21.92031     # notice: sd calculated by hand using 'sd(c(27,58))'
2 38 91 90 67  7 16.26346     # notice: sd calculated by hand using 'sd(c(67,90))'
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what do you expect to be the result for `c(2, 2, 3, 4, 20, 20)` ? Please edit your question!

Comment: @jogo I have a lot of decimals in my data, so your case where there are identical values will not become a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a custom function to do this for you. It takes in a vector, removes the minimum and maximum, and returns the sd of the remaining values. Of course you could also write this as an anonymous function, but sometimes having the function separate makes the code more readable.

```
sd_custom <- function(x){
  x <- x[x!=min(x) & x!=max(x)]
  return(sd(x))
}

dat$sd <- apply(dat[,1:4], 1, sd_custom)

> dat
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5       sd
1 27 58 21 95 63 21.92031
2 38 91 90 67  7 16.26346
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
 dat$sd <- apply(dat[1:4], 1, function(x) sd(x[-c(which.min(x), which.max(x))] ))
 dat
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5       sd
1 27 58 21 95 63 21.92031
2 38 91 90 67  7 16.26346
```

Answer (score 3):

We can modify your code by changing `sd(x)` into a custom function

```
dat <- transform(dat, sd = apply(dat[,1:4], 1, function(x) sd(x[x<max(x) & x>min(x)])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or another option is `range` with `setdiff`

```
dat$sd <- apply(dat[1:4], 1, function(x) sd(setdiff(x,range(x))))
dat$sd
#[1] 21.92031 16.26346
```